# Magento 2 - Load image of group product for simple product

Tags: magento2, product, cart, product-images, magento2.3.4

I created a group product which has two simple products.

I did not upload an image to the simple product, only to the grouped product.

[image]

If I add a simple product into the card, then no images loads:

[image: cart]

How can I make it load the image of the group product, if it does not have an image itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Admin->Store->Configuration->Sales->Checkout->Shopping Cart**

And set the **Parent Product Thumbnail** as **Grouped Product Image**

Check the below screenshot

[image]

Clear the cache and check.

Answer (score -1):

Magento2 doen't support it by default, you have to do customization for this ,

You can create 1 custom column in quote_item table where you can save group product id for the item so when you add product from group product detail page so you have to insert its group id as well. then on item list page you can check if it has group product id then you can fetch group product image and display it.